# kinematics: parabolic movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, simulations, projectile

How does the formula $ax^2$ is affected by the angle and the power of the launch of, let's say, a cannon ball, (regardless of its mass)?
I am trying to create a simulation, and everything I have to improvise failed badly...

Comment: I would read [the wikipedia page about projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Comment: Or also the [Trajectory of a projectile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile) page on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to look at this is to consider separately the horizontal and vertical velocity/position.

For a projectile launched at angle $\theta$ and velocity $v$, the components are:

Horizontal velocity $$v_h = v\cos\theta$$

Vertical velocity $$v_v = v\sin\theta$$

The position at time $t$ is then given by $$(x, y) = (v_h\cdot t, v_v \cdot t - \frac12 g t^2)$$

This is ignoring drag - if that's important, please update your question.